# Building IE8+ add-on

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, ieaddon

I'm a .Net developer and I would like to leverage my knowledge to create an IE add-on.
Basically this add-on should have a button in the toolbar. Once the button is clicked I should save whole page in PDF. Pretty simple task if I new where from to start.

How do I create an add-on for IE?
Is there an VS template project for that?
How to access the current instance of IE to get the page and eventually print it in background to a PDF printer?
Is there another technique to achieve this?
What about the installer?

I found a bunch of nothing via google, and MS site has no concrete example.

Can you give me a couple of suggestions on where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Things like that are usually implemented as [Browser Helper Objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2007/12/07/the-basics-of-browser-helper-objects.aspx), lots of examples if you google for *.net bho*.